# jQuery send string as POST parameters

Tags: ajax, post, jquery

I want to send a string as an ajax Post parameter.

The following code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://nakolesah.ru/",
   data: 'foo=bar&ca$libri=no$libri',
   success: function(msg){
     alert('wow'+msg);
   }
});
```

Is not working. Why?

Comment: I see that you are a PHP developer and I also see that you did this: `ca$libri=no$libri`. Just checking to be sure here...are you sure you're not accidentally trying to use PHP constructions where JS ones should be? If you want to include the value of the `$libri` variable into this string, try this: `'foo=bar&ca' + $libri + '=no' + $libri`.

Comment: nono :) i understand all moments of generating js by php :) it's the names of ajax variables in APS. I create parser that parse some site with ajax. And now i got why error. It's coz crossdomain query. I must to create query first to my server :)

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    // make sure you respect the same origin policy with this url:
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
    url: 'http://nakolesah.ru/',
    data: { 
        'foo': 'bar', 
        'ca$libri': 'no$libri' // <-- the $ sign in the parameter name seems unusual, I would avoid it
    },
    success: function(msg){
        alert('wow' + msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be data: { foo: 'bar' }, without the apostrophe ' ?

Comment: @MariusStanescu, both are equivalent equivalent javascript syntax.

Comment: also pretty sure the $ in the ca$libri is perfectly fine

Comment: Doesn't answer the question regarding posting as string :(, see below answer.

Comment: This works but this doesn't: foo: 'bar' . I have spent 2 days causeless I didn't add the strings signs to both sides!!!

Answer (score 43):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',    
    url:'http://nakolesah.ru/',
    data:'foo='+ bar+'&calibri='+ nolibri,
    success: function(msg){
        alert('wow' + msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: this is why I came here, to find out how to send $.post data as a string. the accepted answer does not at all help me with that. thank you.

Comment: Agreed, I had a situation as well where a string was required for a framework I was developing, good answer.  In my situation I was able to make this work by putting the string in a variable next to data:, the format of my string was '?var=value&var2=value2'

Answer (score 15):

I see that they did not understand your question.

**Answer is:** add `"traditional"` parameter to your ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
  traditional: true,
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: custom,
  success: ok,
  dataType: "json"
});
```

And it will work with parameters PASSED AS A STRING.

Answer (score 12):

For a similar application I had to wrap my `data` object with `JSON.stringify()` like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 
  'foo': 'bar', 
  'ca$libri': 'no$libri'
}),
```

The API was working with a REST client but couldn't get it to function with jquery ajax in the browser. stringify was the solution.

Comment: Why we had to do this?

Comment: Not sure but some characters in the response must not be considered strings unless forced.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether this is still actual.. just for future readers.
If what you really want is to pass your parameters as part of the URL, you should probably use  [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question.. But following is the only syntax that used to work for me -

```
data: '{"winNumber": "' + win + '"}',
```

And the parameter-name match with the argument of the server method

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the problem in passing string value to string parameters in Ajax. After so much googling, i have come up with a custom solution as below.

```
var bar = 'xyz';
var calibri = 'no$libri';

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: "http://nakolesah.ru/",
   data: '{ foo: \'' + bar + '\', zoo: \'' + calibri + '\'}',
   success: function(msg){
       alert('wow'+msg);
   },
});
```

Here, **bar** and **calibri** are two string variables and you can pass whatever string value to respective string parameters in web method.

Comment: Meh.  I don't recommend manually crafting a json string via string concatenation -- you become vulnerable to a variable breaking your string (creating an invalid json string).

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this exact problem. But I have got a solution and it worked perfectly. I have needed to pass the parameters which are already produced by javascript function. So below code is working for me. I used **ColdFusion** for the backend. I just directly used the parameters as a variable.

```
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "https://myexampleurl.com/myactionfile.cfm",
                    type: "POST",
                    data : {paramert1: variable1,parameter2: variable2},
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);                              
                    } )};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, encode the POST request as a string and pass to the data parameter,

```
var requestData = "Param1=" + encodeURIComponent(jsParam1) + "&Param2="+ encodeURIComponent(jsParam2);

var request = $.ajax({
                            url: page + "?" + getVars,
                            method: "POST",
                            data: requestData,
                            dataType: "html",
                            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    });
```