# Ajax post request string data instead of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046930/jquery-send-string-as-post-parameters) I need to send a string as data in a post request.

Unlike that one, I can't use an object because I have repeated items. As you can see in my sample data sn1, sn2 and sn3 are repeated several times on different datetimes.

Sample data:

`&sn3=2013-2-4T12:43:52&sn3=2013-2-4T12:43:55&sn1=2013-2-4T12:43:59&sn1=2013-2-4T12:44:0&sn2=2013-2-4T12:44:0&sn3=2013-2-4T12:44:2&sn2=2013-2-4T12:44:3&sn3=2013-2-4T12:44:19&sn3=2013-2-4T12:44:19&sn3=2013-2-4T12:44:19&sn2=2013-2-4T12:44:19&sn3=2013-2-4T12:44:21&sn2=2013-2-4T12:44:22&sn2=2013-2-4T12:46:39&sn3=2013-2-4T12:46:42&sn2=2013-2-4T12:46:44&sn2=2013-2-4T12:46:45&sn2=2013-2-4T12:46:46&sn2=2013-2-4T12:47:27&sn2=2013-2-4T12:47:27&sn2=2013-2-4T12:49:44&sn2=2013-2-4T12:50:21&sn2=2013-2-4T12:52:21&sn2=2013-2-4T12:52:24&sn2=2013-2-4T12:57:35&sn3=2013-2-4T12:57:38&sn3=2013-2-4T12:57:39&sn2=2013-2-4T12:57:39&sn2=2013-2-4T12:57:40&sn3=2013-2-4T12:57:46&sn3=2013-2-4T13:21:30`

I tried using the following

```
console.log(screens); //logs my sample data posted above.
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType : 'text',
            data : screens,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("sucessfull sending:")
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log('failed');
            }

        });
```

But it always triggers failed.

Can I send it as a string? If not, how can I send multiple items with the same key?

Comment: Does the Network tab in the debugger console show an error? what is the error in the return argument of the error function? Also, change your error function to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`, then you can see the error message in `errorThrown`. you can also get more information inspecting the other 2 arguments in the error event handler. What is the error message you get?

Comment: I don't have a network tab. I'm developing this using phonegap so I don't have access to the amazing debugger console. I didn't bother to log everything as we went with another solution! Thank you!

Comment: Ah, I see. At least you can make use of the error handler arguments in future if you ever need to. sorry about that, didn't realise you were using phonegap.

Comment: Probably because I didn't mentioned it :). I get half of the usual replies if I add phonegap in the tag. Your comment was very helpful mostly because I've never noticed we had a Network tab in the console, and it's very handy. I come from a mobile background and phonegap hates me. So every bit helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    console.log(screens); //logs my sample data posted above.
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType : 'text',
        data : {screens:screens},
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("sucessfull sending:")
            console.log(data);
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log('failed');
        }

    });
```

See `data : {screens:screens},`, if you do something like that, on server you will be able to get it like: `screensString = Request["screens"]`. After that, screensString will contain a single string with all screens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is what I went for. Replaced the &s on my string for |s and the server can split and use it.

Comment: Hm. If I'm not missing something important, you should be able to use `&` same way as `|`. Without any replacement.

Comment: Probably. But why to risk? I'm sure I can use `|`. Better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify contentType in the ajax options, your request will default to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'.
However, when your post data is just text, you should make the server aware of that fact by specifying a contentType 'text'.
As opposed to the contentType, the dataType specifies the type of response data that you expect back from the server.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem but I didn't know about the contentType param. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to use [] in your parameters.

instead of sending `&sn3=` multiple times (which is rewriting itself) send it as an array like this `&sn3[]=`

if you are getting this data from an form input use `name="sn3[]"` and if this is the case, I would recommend you use `$('#yourform').serialize()` as data sent

Comment: +1, that is a good suggestion as well, but we went for the other one. The server would have to parse the string anyway and this was extra work for the client.

Comment: Just as note: it depends on server how `[]` will be handled. In php you will get nice array. In asp.net - you will get one item which contains all `sn3[]` values separated with `|`, as I remember.

Comment: thanks, by the way, correcting what you said (gameower) the server will get an array not a string