# How to print table from php file to TCPDF in following scenario?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, tcpdf

I have a php file(add_member.php). I'm creating a dynamic table by executing SQL query. The code of this file is as follows:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM member_details WHERE lname='ABC';

$n = new data();

$res = $n -> querySend($sql);

?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
   <tr>
      <td align="center"></td>
      <td align="center">First Name</td>
      <td align="center">Last Name</td>
      <td align="center">Caste</td>
      <td align="center">Residence address</td>
      <td align="center">Education</td>
   </tr>
   <?php

       $i=1;

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
       { 
           $member_no = $row['member_no'];

           $total_member = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_member FROM family_member_details WHERE member_no =" .$member_no;

           $total_res = $n -> querySend($total_member);

           $row_total = mysql_fetch_array($total_res);        

          ?>

           <tr>
               <td align="center" rowspan="<?php echo $row_total['total_member']+1;?>"><?php echo $i;?></td>
               <td align="center"><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
               <td align="center"><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
               <td align="center"><?php echo $row['caste'];?></td>
               <td align="center"><?php echo $row['residence_addr'];?></td>
               <td align="center"><?php echo $row['education'];?></td>
           </tr>
           <?php 
                $family_sql = "SELECT * from family_member_details WHERE member_no = $member_no";
                $family_res = $n -> querySend($family_sql);

                while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($family_res))
                {
                   ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $row1['name']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $row1['name']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $row1['name']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $row1['name']?></td>
                        <td align="center"><?php echo $row1['name']?></td>
                    </tr>   
         <?php  }
                $i++; 
          } ?>
    </table>
```

Now upon clicking on a button I want to create the same table into PDF file. For this purpose I decided to use TCPDF library. But for it I've to provide the HTML content to TCPDF file. Now my issue is how should I get the HTML of a dynamically generated table from PHP file and write this content to the text file? Can anyone please help me in this regard? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of displaying your table directly to the browser page, simply store the text in a variable and echo it...then you can send the var to the TCPDF library.

```
$dyn_table = '<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1"><tr><td align="center">/td><th align="center">First Name</th><th align="center">Last Name</th><th align="center">Caste</th><th align="center">Residence address</th><th align="center">Education</th></tr>';

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $member_no = $row['member_no'];
    $total_member = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_member FROM family_member_details WHERE member_no =" . $member_no;

    $total_res = $n->querySend($total_member);

    $row_total = mysql_fetch_array($total_res);

    $dyn_table .= '<tr><td align="center" rowspan="' . $row_total['total_member'] + 1 . '">' . $i . '</td><td align="center">' . $row['fname'] . '</td><td align="center">' . $row['lname'] . '</td><td align="center">' . $row['caste'] . '</td><td align="center">' . $row['residence_addr'] . '</td><td align="center">' . $row['education'] . '</td></tr>';

    $family_sql = "SELECT * from family_member_details WHERE member_no = $member_no";
    $family_res = $n->querySend($family_sql);

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($family_res)) {
        $dyn_table .= '<tr><td align="center">' . $row1['name'] . '</td><td align="center">' . $row1['name'] . '</td><td align="center">' . $row1['name'] . '</td><td align="center">' . $row1['name'] . '</td><td align="center">' . $row1['name'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $i++;
}
$dyn_table .= '</table>';
echo $dyn_table;
```

#### EDIT

In order to post this html to your TCPDF library, I would use AJAX to prevent another page request/load. I prefer to use [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) as it simplifies this process immensely. Here is one way you could do it:

```
<input type="button" name="TCPDF" id="submitToTCPDF" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = 'php/script/to/handle/post';
    var data = {'table_html': '<? echo $dyn_table; ?>'};

    $('#TCPDF').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function($result){
                // Do whatever after html is submitted


            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can read more about [Jquery's AJAX post method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in [**this StackOverflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046930/jquery-send-string-as-post-parameters).

Comment: suppose after echo $dyn_table; there is <input type="button" name="tcpdf"/> then how to send that var to tcpdf library onclick of a button?

Comment: I updated my answer to help show how to go about performing an AJAX request as further shown in the link at the bottom of the answer.