# Passing JSON string from javascript to PHP web service

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html, jsonp

I have to send details to the web service. I have made a JSON string in which the details are stored, `str_table` is the JSON string which I have to pass to the web service.

I tried many things from Google, but nothing worked.  Following is among those things which I tried. Please check where I am going wrong.

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"hostname/proj_folder/name.php?content="+str_table,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   crossDomain:true,
   dataType:'json',
   success: alert("in success"),
   error: alert("in error")    
});
```

I have used data in the following code, and now it alerts `error[object Object]`

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"hostname/proj_folder/name.php?",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data:JSON.stringify('content='+str_table),
            crossDomain:true,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
                alert('succes' + data);
            },
        error: function(data){
                alert('error' + data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I can already see that your `success` and `error` handlers are broken. They will simply alert two messages and then set the handlers to `undefined`. I'm also wondering why you aren't using the `data` option like documented in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#entry-examples

Comment: have you tried debugging using chrome console or firebug ? I think you are not being alerted because your `alert()` should be within anonymous  `function(data) { }` handler after `success:` and `error:` labels

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme: Yes exactly, it simply gives those 2 alerts. I have tried with data too, but doesn't work. I had referred the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046930/jquery-send-string-as-post-parameters    I am sending 5 different things by storing them in JSON string. But at the server side nothing is inserted into tables.

Comment: @Deepika What happens when you send the exact same request to the url directly using your browser ? Does the content get inserted then ? If not then your server side code does not work.

Comment: Any access denied error in console (Origin xxxx is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin)? Are you sending the request to a cross domain host? As @Anupam mentioned, you need to assign a function to success and error label.

Comment: @Anupam The content gets inserted on server side. The JSON string is created at my side and I have stored it in local storage. When the same string is run on browser on server side, the content gets inserted. Please find the edits.

Comment: @Chickenrice no such error.

Comment: @Deepika What does the HTTP response header contain ? ( See in console, or firebug)

Comment: @Deepika Also, if `str_table` is already a JSON string you don't want to stringify it again, You are probably looking to do `JSON.parse()`. And you should also get rid of `?` at the end of URL. The idea of query string applies only to GET, not POST.