# Sending data ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page called post-blog.php, in here I've set-up a blog entry. I have all this data being saved into one variable. Its displaying this data in an array.

```
var data = title + content + image + datetime + categories;
```

How can I send this data to another page called publish.php and redirect the user to that page ? 
I've tried to set up a ajax to do this but its not working. Any suggestions ?

```
  $.ajax({
        type:   'POST',
        cache:    false,
        url:      'publish.php',
        data:     data,
        success:  function( data ) {

          alert ( data );

        }

      });

      return false;

    });
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more details on what you want as a result?

Comment: Right I have a variable called data which is holding information, when the user clicks on the button I want the var data to be (Temporally saved) and sent  to publish.php , but I also want it to send the user to that page automatically. On that page I just want to alert(data) and show the information in var data

Comment: Is this helpful ? Thanks for your response

Comment: Yes its helpful, I would suggest [this](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php#98419). You can give the parameters through the URL to the next page.

Comment: Why are you using Ajax if you have to redirect to another page? Just use simple post!!

Comment: I dont have to use Ajax Im new to this so I thought Ajax would be more useful?

Comment: Ryan ajax is mostly used only if you want the data to be posted to some page without redirection. I don't think you need to use ajax here. As long as your purpose is to learn. You are very welcome.

Comment: @RyanHolmes Yea, you can just use `$_POST` or `$_GET` for this. Ajax isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks so you would recommenced sending the data value to another page via php?

Comment: You also need to wrap your ajax function inside $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: @RyanHolmes I guess you wanted to do something like this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the problem, you need to pass the data to a new page and open that page.

If this is your question then this can be done without AJAX, basically AJAX does not even provide solution here. Instead you can just pass all the data to your new page in query format as below -

```
var page = 'publish.php?title='+title+ '&content='+content+'&image='+image+ '&datetime='+datetime+'&categories='+categories;
```

Then just change the window location as below

`window.location.href = page;`

And to get all those variables in your PHP file, do the following in `publish.php` on top -

```
if($_GET['title'])
{
  $title = $_GET['title'];
}
// similarly get all the data in publish.php file and continue with your page
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for, sorry i'm new and didnt reaslise you needed to ajax.

Comment: I'm getting a error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier    By the var page ?

Comment: can you please paste your `data` content here.. and full error ?

Comment: Right I'm not getting errors anymore mistake on my part. Its not redirecting to page though   
var page = 'publish.php?title='+title+ '&content='+content+'&image='+image+ '&datetime='+datetime;


window.location.href = page;

Comment: Can you please post the value of `page` variable ?  and where you are putting this in your code ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've added all the jquery on the button click here - https://jsfiddle.net/ueLft8x2/ .  The code wont run because its using other functions on the page. Is this useful?

Comment: I've uploaded all the code in that section here. The functions wont run because that gathering the data which is done elsewhere [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ueLft8x2/) Is this helpful?

Comment: `var page = 'publish.php?title='+title+ '&content='+content+'&image='+image+ '&datetime='+datetime+'&categories='+categories;` + was missed before categories.

Comment: does this work for you? I tried and it worked for me. corrected in answer as well.

Comment: The var is storing the correct information, but not redirecting ?

Comment: paste here the redirection code that you are using ?

Comment: window.location.href = page;

Comment: use this one `window.location = page;`. One thing you also want to try is putting the absolute url. ie `var page = 'http://....'` like this..

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming all your variables are strings. If they are not, for example the datetime may be an object, change them into a string first.

Docs say [Object must be Key/Value pairs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or a string.

Objects work well for this, try something like:

```
var data = {title: title, content: content, image: image, datetime: datetime, categories: categories};
```

If your data is coming from a form check out [jQuery's serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

I've never tried to pass as a string in a POST, but my gut feeling is it would need to be in a format similar to passing the data through the url.

```
var data = 'title=' + title + '&content=' + content;
```

Also keep in mind the `data` in the success function is not the same as what is being passed to the php page. This is what the php page will return. If you're php page returns nothing your alert will be empty. When I'm testing I like to throw something like `echo $_POST['title'];` in the php file to see something come back.

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046930/jquery-send-string-as-post-parameters) that might help too.

Comment: Updated the response; I know the docs say it accepts a string but I've always had better luck as an object.