# Pass variable to another page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php

## **This My test.php file** ##

```
 //here I am getting the variable value

<?PHP
 $name = $_POST('variable');
 echo $name;
?>
```

## **This my script** ##

```
 //avariable value passing to test .php file

<script type ="text/javascript">
  var name = "jani";
  $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'test/test.php',
          data: {'variable': name},
          });
</script>
```

###** I am getting this error  **###

```
 Fatal error: Function name must be a string in 
                 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 2
```

Comment: Check console while you are making ajax call, are there any values passing?

Comment: no values are passing in console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery send string as POST parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046930/jquery-send-string-as-post-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Change your **test.php code** `use square bracket not round for super global variable` as below,

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['variable'])) {
    $name = $_POST['variable'];
    echo $name;
}
?>
```

Comment: $name = $_POST['variable']; echo $name; but i am getting undefined variable error

Comment: @Jani I have updated my answer. check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will definitely work:
My PHP File:

```
<script>
var name = "name";
var url = "test/test.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'name': name},
           success: function (data) {
            console.log(date);
           }
});
</script>
```

Where ajax request recieves:

```
//here I am getting the variable value

<?PHP
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 echo $name;
?>
```

After Your latest comment I have added js fiddle link
before running it open console and POST besides headers section you can see data has been posted.
[Js Fiddle Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ohv3e60q/)

Comment: Undefined index: name in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 5 getting this error

Comment: check console this time while sending ajax request is it sending parameters?

Comment: Undefined index: name in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php

Comment: have you checked Console? What parameters have you sending?

Comment: I have updated the answer and added the link, you can see it