# ajax variable is not passing to controller using codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am converting my timesheet to a CSV file. I need to filter it using `user_id`, `start_date` and `end_date`. After filtering, it converts the whole file to a CSV file but not including the filtering.

On clicking download, I have sent `start_date` and `end_date` using AJAX to my controller. However, I am getting only empty values for such data. Can you help me and suggest to me why the data is not printed correctly in my controller?

AJAX code on clicking download is:

```
    function get_csv()
     {
        var user_id=$('#user').val();
        var start_date=$('#start_date').val();
        var end_date=$('#end_date').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/timesheetmanager/timesheet/getcsv",
            data: '&start_date='+start_date+'&end_date='+end_date,
            success: function(data){
                document.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('timesheetmanager/timesheet/getcsv/'); ?>'+'/'+user_id;
            }
            });
     }
```

Controller :

```
    function getcsv($user_id)
        {       
            $userid=$user_id;   
            $start_date=$this->input->post('start_date');
            $end_date=$this->input->post('end_date');
            $this->db->where('id',$userid);
            $user_query=$this->db->get('users');
            $user_result=$user_query->row();
            if($userid != "0")
                {
                    $this->db->where('emp_id',$userid);
                }
                if(($start_date != 'Start Date')&& ($end_date != 'End Date'))
                    {
                        $startdate=@date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('start_date')));
                        $enddate=@date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('end_date')));
                        $datequery= $this->db->where("update_date BETWEEN '$startdate' and '$enddate'");        
                    }
            $header_name=array('TASK NAME','DESCRIPTION','HOURS SPEND','DATE');
            $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
            $query = $this->db->get('timesheet');
            $this->db->where('emp_id',$userid);
            $getRes = $query->result_array();
            $filename = ''.$name.date('Y-m-d').'.csv';
            header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
            $finalData[]=$user_result->name;
            $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($output,$header_name);
            $finalData = array();
            $fp = fopen('php://output','w');
            foreach( $getRes as  $data)
            {
                $finalData[]=$data['task_name'];
                $finalData[]=$data['description'];
                $finalData[]=$data['hours_spend'];
                $finalData[]=$data['update_date'];
                fputcsv($output, $finalData);
                unset($finalData);
            }
            fclose($fp);

        }
```

Comment: timesheet is in what format?  Excel?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5046951/578855 to see how to send post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 function get_csv()
 {
    var user_id=$('#user').val();
    var start_date=$('#start_date').val();
    var end_date=$('#end_date').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/timesheetmanager/timesheet/getcsv/"+user_id,
        data: {'start_date': start_date,'end_date':end_date},
        success: function(data){
            document.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('timesheetmanager/timesheet/getcsv/'); ?>'+'/'+user_id;
        }
        });
 }
```

Comment: When I disable  (document.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('timesheetmanager/timesheet/getcsv/'); ?>'+'/'+user_id;) this line, the parameter values are passing.